# Difference between "about" and "Around"

Tags: differences, british-english, sentence

What is the difference between "`about`" and "`around`" in following example ?

```
I'll see you around 6 O'clock.

I'll see you about 6 O'clock.
```

Now, I usually the first one, but I heard the second one on the phone from one of my friends (native English speaker).

Thanks.

Comment: You'll find it interesting, I'm sure, that some people actually put the two together:  *I'll see you around about 6 o'clock.*  A colloquial expression to be sure but used nonetheless.

Comment: That is really interesting. But which one is right between the two ?

Comment: With respect to approximate times they are interchangeable- there's no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No implied difference in meaning whatever.

Answer (score 1):

They mean both the same. As *preposition*, around is **the same** as about.